# How to combine two table rows where a series of conditions are met

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I am working on a parsing program that parses info from **two files** into a
sqlite3 table.

Lets say the table has the following values:
filename, value2, value3, value4

There are **never more than two filename values in the table**,
I would like to write a **sql query** that will **join two rows when** the following
**conditions are true**:

- row X:filename != row Y:filename
- row X:value2 == row Y:value2
- row X:value3 == row Y:value3
- row X:value4 == row Y:value4

---

Ok the actual program I am working on is a little more complicated so maybe this will be a little clearer

file1.txt contents

> ```
> abcd, 1234, efgh
> klmn, 5678, opqr
> stuv, 9abc, wxyz
> ```

file2.txt contents

> ```
> abcd, 1234, efgh
> klmn, 9ffx, opqr
> stuv, 9abc, wxyz
> ```

Desired Output:

- file1.txt, abcd, 1234, efgh file2.txt, abcd, 1234, efgh
- file1.txt, klmn, 5678, opqr, --, --, --, --
- --,--,--,--, file2.txt klmn, fffx, opqr
- file1.txt, stuv, 9abc, wxyz, file2.txt, stuv, 9abc, wxyz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` below is the table name

```
select a.*, b.*
from x as a
inner join x as b
  on a.filename<b.filename
    and a.value2 = b.value2
        and a.value3 = b.value3
        and a.value4 = b.value4
union all
select a.*, b.*
from x as a
left join x as b
  on a.filename!=b.filename
        and a.value2 = b.value2
        and a.value3 = b.value3
        and a.value4 = b.value4
where b.filename is null
  and a.filename = (select min(filename) from x)
union all
select b.*, a.*
from x as a
left join x as b
  on a.filename!=b.filename
        and a.value2 = b.value2
        and a.value3 = b.value3
        and a.value4 = b.value4
where b.filename is null
  and a.filename = (select max(filename) from x)
```

There are three parts

1. Where all values match between the two files. The lesser file name is listed on the left side
2. Where the values cannot be matched to the right side. `min(filename)` filters only for unmatched left-file rows.
3. Where the values cannot be matched to the left side. `max(filename)` filters only for unmatched right-file rows.

There is no way to produce your output order exactly (some inherent sort order) unless there exists some line number column, which can be spliced into the query.

Comment: Suppose I didn't want to view the whole list at once. How could I shorten the list so that only results where a.value2 and b.value2 = '1234'? A solution I found is: create view if not exists myview as ... Then creating a select * from myview where value2='1234' Is there a better/faster way of doing this by modifying the code above?

Comment: @Tom that is too ambiguous - which value2? Note that if you create a view, you must name each column since there are two of each column from the table aliased twice. In any case, if you want a.value2=b.value2=<somevalue>, put a filter on the first part only (before Union all) and ignore the rest of the query